# Permissions are blank when trying to load satellite images from Planet API

Tags: python, imagery, satellite, rasterio, postgis-raster

I am trying to download the map of Melbourne using Planet API. I have given AOI coordinates of Melbourne. When I run the code the permissions are returning blank ("_permissions": []). I cannot able to view analytic_dn or analytic data to load the images.

```
import os
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

os.environ['APIKEY']='HERE YOU INPUT YOU API 
Key'

# API Key stored as an env variable
PLANET_API_KEY = os.getenv('APIKEY') 

# will get a 4 band image with spectral data for Red, Green, Blue and 
Near-infrared values
item_type = "PSOrthoTile"

# API request object
search_request = {
"interval": "day",
"item_types": [item_type], 
"filter": combined_filter
}

# fire off the POST request
search_result = \
requests.post(
'https://api.planet.com/data/v1/quick-search',
auth=HTTPBasicAuth('APIKEY', ''),
json=search_request)

print(json.dumps(search_result.json(), indent=1))
```

This should return permissions for the particular coordinates. I don't 
whether its the problem of my API ID or not.

Comment: If that is your real API key, I would delete it and change it immediately, you've just exposed it to the internet...  You have `os.environ['long string of characters']='Some text'`.  Do you actually mean `os.environ['PLANET_API_KEY']='long string of characters'`? You also try to read that back in using `os.getenv('API KEY') ` but env var names can't have spaces. Then you pass the literal string `'API KEY'` to `HTTPBasicAuth` instead of the actual key.

Comment: The API key is in string format and there are no spaces in it.

Comment: I did not say anything about spaces in the API key string. You can't have spaces in a env car *name*. You can have pretty much anything you want in an env var *value*

Comment: Are you saying that i am not sending actual key parameter to HTTPBasicAuth?

Comment: Yes. You are passing the literal string `"APIKEY"`

Comment: should i change anything in the code? If there are any changes can you please specify me.

Comment: It is only working for specific coordinates. It is not working for any random coordinates.

Comment: Just a guess, try passing the `PLANET_API_KEY` variable instead. `auth=HTTPBasicAuth(PLANET_API_KEY, ''),`